# How to return new array with dynamically populated properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

So my call returns something like:

```
data:
        {
          nameData: 'Test33333',
          emailData: email@email.com,
          urlLink: link.com
          additionalDetails: [
               {
                 field: 'email',
                 value: 'other@email.com'
                },
                {
                 field: 'name', 
                 value: 'name1223'
                }
            ]
         }
```

Now, I want to make a function that would take the passed parameter (data) and make an array of objects, that should look like below. It should be done in more **generic** way.

Array output expectation:

```
fullData = [
      {
        name: 'data_name'
        value: 'Test33333'
      },
      {
        name: 'data_email',
        value: 'email@email.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'data_url',
        value: 'Link.com'
      },
      extraData: [
        //we never know which one will it return
      ]
];
```

It should be done in the function, with name, for example:

```
generateDataFromObj(data)
```

so

```
generateDataArrFromObj = (data) => {
    //logic here that will map correctly the data
}
```

How can this be achieved? I am not really proficient with JavaScript, thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck (and what the rules are for going from the property name, like `urlLink`, to the `name` value like `"data_url"`). People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you keep your data property keys in camelCase this will work for any data you add, not just the data in the example. Here I've used `planetLink`. It [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)s over the object keys using an initial empty array), extracts the new key name from the existing property key, and concatenates each new object to the returned array.

```js
const data = { nameData: 'Test33333', emailData: 'email@email.com', planetLink: 'Mars' };

function generateDataArrFromObj(data) {
  const regex = /([a-z]+)[A-Z]/;

  // `reduce` over the object keys
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, c) => {

    // match against the lowercase part of the key value
    // and create the new key name `data_x`
    const key = `data_${c.match(regex)[1]}`;
    return acc.concat({ name: key, value: data[c] });
  }, []);
}

console.log(generateDataArrFromObj(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a map over the object keys, this will return an array populated by each item, then in the func map runs over each item, build an object like so:

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(key => {return {name: key, value: myObj[key]}})
```

Comment: Watch out, the output object has key names that are different from the original.